# awk: search and concatenate string in a single line

Tags: awk, sed

I've a text file with this data

```
set( VERSION_MAJOR 1 ) 
set( VERSION_MINOR 2 )
set( VERSION_PATCH 3 )
```

I'm looking to make a string like this and save in a new file.

```
VERSION 1.2.3
```

I tried following code,

```
$ awk  '/VERSION_MAJOR/ {print $3; exit} ' version.txt >> version.in
$ awk  '/VERSION_MINOR/ {print $3; exit} ' version.txt >> version.in
$ awk  '/VERSION_PATCH/ {print $3; exit} ' version.txt >> version.in
$ cat version.in 
1
2
3
```

As you can see I can search/parse the individual versions, but unable to concatenate them in a single string such as `1.2.3`.

How can I do this with `awk` or `sed`?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't downvote but the forum exists to help people with their code, not as a free code writing service so `How can I do this with awk or sed or any other combination of bash commands?` isn't an appropriate question. Post your attempt so we can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, not sure how else can I frame the question. I guess I'll make the question more specific

Comment: Write some code to try to solve the problem. Include that code in your question. Ask what's wrong with your code (assuming it doesn't do what you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions:

- there may be other lines in the file besides the 3x `VERSION_` entries
- spacing is exactly as depicted in the example, ie, the desired numbers are in the 3rd space-delimited field

If you find yourself calling `awk` multiple times chances are pretty good you can do the whole thing with a single `awk` call;  one idea combining OP's current code into a single `awk` call:

```
awk '
/VERSION_MAJOR/ { maj=$3 }
/VERSION_MINOR/ { min=$3 }
/VERSION_PATCH/ { pat=$3 } 
END             { printf "VERSION %d.%d.%d\n", maj, min, pat }
' version.txt
```

This generates:

```
VERSION 1.2.3
```

**NOTE:** if one of the `VERSION_` entries is missing then the `%d` will cause the associated undefined `awk` variable to display as a `0`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;N;s/[^0-9\n]//g;y/\n/./;s/^/VERSION /' file
```

Append all lines.

Remove extraneous material.

Translate newlines to `.`'s

Insert `VERSION`  text.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample input file accurately depicts everything the file contains then all you need is:

```
$ awk '{v=v s $3; s="."} END{print "VERSION", v}' version.txt
VERSION 1.2.3
```

Answer (score -2):

```
{m,g}awk 'sub("^[.]*","VERSION ",$!--NF)' RS='^$' FS='[^0-9.]+' OFS='.'
```

=

```
VERSION 1.2.3
```